# How to set domain for cookie in the Spring MVC web app?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, cookies

I have a Spring MVC app where I want to manually add cookie for page. The code below demonstrates the way I am doing it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add-cookie",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addCookie(HttpServletResponse response) {

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookiename", "cookievalue");
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return "<html></html>"
    }
```

This code works fine and adds cookie as expected. But I want to add cookie with specific domain. So I add this line `cookie.setDomain("mydomain.com");` after declaring `cookie` object. Now instead of adding cookie with this domain it does not add cookie at all.

So is it possible to add cookie with specific domain to your page? And how to do it?

Comment: Yes you can but it has to match the domain you are using it for. So you cannot just add arbitrary cookies for any domain.

Comment: When I do not set domain it adds cookie with default domain (localhost in my case). So can I change domain to different one?

Comment: Apparently your request is coming in at localhost. It will match the domain of the response. You cannot change that to be say `cnn.com` ... Would be a nice security leak if that would be possible would't it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I should learn more about cookies. :)